# if statement on 3 conditions in R

Tags: r

I see some issues in my if statement. The output I get is wrong than what i expected.

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c(-16,-9,-48,20,-39), b = c(2, -4, -2, 2, 4), c = c(9, -14, 23, -13, -6))
if(asd$a < 0 && asd$b>0 && asd$c>0){
  asd$d <- "Inv"
} else {
  asd$d <- "NotInv"
}
> asd
    a  b   c   d
1 -16  2   9 Inv
2  -9 -4 -14 Inv
3 -48 -2  23 Inv
4  20  2 -13 Inv
5 -39  4  -6 Inv
```

Expected output

```
> asd
    a  b   c   d
1 -16  2   9 Inv
2  -9 -4 -14 Not Inv
3 -48 -2  23 Not Inv
4  20  2 -13 Not Inv
5 -39  4  -6 Not Inv
```

Comment: Because `&&` and `||` return only the first value; use `&` and `|` instead which are vectorized. `

Answer (score 3):

with base `R`:

```
asd$d <- "Not Inv"
asd$d[asd$a < 0 & asd$b>0 & asd$c>0] <- "Inv"
asd

    a  b   c       d
1 -16  2   9     Inv
2  -9 -4 -14 Not Inv
3 -48 -2  23 Not Inv
4  20  2 -13 Not Inv
5 -39  4  -6 Not Inv
```

with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
asd %>% mutate(d = if_else(a < 0 & b>0 & c>0,"Inv","Not Inv"))

    a  b   c       d
1 -16  2   9     Inv
2  -9 -4 -14 Not Inv
3 -48 -2  23 Not Inv
4  20  2 -13 Not Inv
5 -39  4  -6 Not Inv
```

You got a wrong result because you used `&&` instead of `&` :

```
asd$a < 0 && asd$b>0 && asd$c>0
[1] TRUE
```

Meaning that only `if` statement is executed :

```
asd$d <- "Inv"
```

Using `&` instead gives the expected vectorized result:

```
asd$a < 0 & asd$b>0 & asd$c>0
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: @imran, did it answer your question?